# Apollo Federations

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm following the very basic tutorial in GraphQL Federations and trying to run an Apollo Servers
as below:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
const { ApolloGateway } = require("@apollo/gateway");

const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
    serviceList: [
        { name: "integrations", url: "http://localhost:5000/integrations" },
        // List of federation-capable GraphQL endpoints...
    ]
});

const server = new ApolloServer({ gateway });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

But I am constantly hitting an error of `Class constructor GraphQLNonNull cannot be invoked without 'new'`. I have checked the open/closed issues in the git repo and seems no one is having similar problems with me.

my node version is v14.15.1
my npm libraries versions:

```
"@apollo/gateway": "^0.44.0",
"apollo-server": "^3.5.0",
"graphql": "^16.0.1"
```

Appreciate it if I can get any leads from anyone, cheers.

Comment: Could you add your tsconfig?

Comment: Hi Timon, I'm using pure js.

Answer (score 1):

It problem happens to be coming from the version of graphql. I downgraded it to graphql 15.0.0 everything works fine.